# Data Extension Field update while adding data from another data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

Extension Update-

I have two data extension Data Extension "A" and Data Extension "B".
i want to add the data of Data Extension "B" to Data Extension "A".
Now the problem is - 
In Data Extension "A" there is a field  (language) which store "FC" and "EC" value. and the Data Extension "B" the same field ( language) store the value fr-ca and en-ca.
While adding the data into the Data Extension "A" and i want to convert the value from fr-ca to FC and en-ca to EC , then want to store into the Data Extension "A".
any solution for this? Expert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do is a [SQL CASE](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-case/) statement to conditionally change the value to insert into the DE based on a value from your source DE.

So it would be:

```
SELECT Field1,
       Field2,
       Field3,
       CASE
           WHEN Language = "fr-ca" THEN "FC"
           WHEN Language = "en-ca" THEN "EC"
           ELSE "Default value" /* If needed */
       END as Language,
       CASE /* Added based off comment */
           WHEN Language = "fr-ca" THEN "QC"
           ELSE "Default value" /* If needed */
       END as Prov
FROM [yourDE_B]

/* Target: yourDE_A */
/* Action: Update */
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gortonington, i will try this!!

Comment: Hey @Gortonington it works! Thank you!

Comment: I have another case - 
I want to change the value of another filed based on the language field.
IF Language = fr-ca then set Prov = QC. ( Prov is another field)
How I can do this?

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your above request.